# How can I integrate a java component in a Eclipse job (with progress monitoring)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing a java component that needs to run both on the command line and as a Eclipse job. The execution can take a few minutes, so I want to inform the user what's happening. I don't want to have a dependency to the Eclipse progress monitor package in my "pure" java code.

How can I provide progress monitoring in the Eclipse job without "polluting" my java code with Eclipse depenendcies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own progress monitor interface that you use in your code, something like:

```
interface MyProgressMonitor
{
  public void beginTask(String name, int totalWork);

  public void done();

  public boolean isCanceled();

  public void worked(int work);
}
```

For the Java application you can use an implementation of this that does nothing.

For the Eclipse job use an implementation that delegates to the Eclipse IProgressMonitor:

```
class EclipseMyProgressMonitor implements MyProgressMonitor
{
  private final IProgressMonitor monitor;

  EclipseMyProgressMonitor(IProgressMonitor theMonitor)
  {
    monitor = theMonitor;
  }

  public void beginTask(String name, int totalWork)
  {
    monitor.beginTask(name, totalWork);
  }

  public void done()
  {
    monitor.done();
  }

  public boolean isCanceled()
  {
    return monitor.isCanceled();
  }

  public void worked(int work)
  {
    monitor.worked(work);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be that difficult. Create the java component in a separate project using just pure java. Then create the eclipse functionality responsible for starting the job, see [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html) for assistance. You eclise code will start a job, this will in turn call your java component.

Issues that will be difficult to handle:

- The user may want to abort the operation, you should try to handle this gracefully in your component. If you are just doing computations, you could kill the job, but if you do something that may require clean up, such as writing a file, you will need some other way to deal with it.
- Ideally you would like to report a correct and realiable progress to the user, but that will introduce a dependency to `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor` which you may not want.

Comment: Regarding bullet 2: Yes, this is my actual question.